# What is the use of honor without help & service?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

In *John Wick 3 Parabellum (2019)*, Bowery King says to Tick Tok man:

> Let it be known the bowery will **honor** the excommunicado. **No help, no
>   services** of any kind.

What is the use of honor without help & service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Bowery King says they will honor the excommunicado he is saying that they agree to adhere to the terms, much like when someone agrees to honor the terms of a contract.

In the case of the excommunicado it means they agree to supply no assistance to John Wick.